# message passing through url in php

Tags: php

I am making a email verification for my website .And after confirming the email i want to redirect the page to with Email Id as post variable.Difficulty is - I am not able to get the email id on the redirected page

```
if($result2){
echo"your profile is active";
?>
<a href=" fill_profile.php?email=<?php $email?>">fill profile </a>
<?php
$sql3="DELETE FROM $tbl_name1 WHERE confirm_code = '$passkey'";
$result3=mysql_query($sql3);

}

}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="fill_profile.php?email=<?php echo $email; ?>">fill profile </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to `echo` the email to browser, so it is not appearing in url. Anything you want to send browser should be `echo`'ed.

```
if($result2){
echo"your profile is active";
?>
<a href=" fill_profile.php?email=<?php echo $email?>">fill profile </a>
<?php
$sql3="DELETE FROM $tbl_name1 WHERE confirm_code = '$passkey'";
$result3=mysql_query($sql3);

}

}
?>
```